# Cannot use Linq to sql due to System.Data.Linq being unavailable

Tags: asp.net

I am new to webforms. I am trying to setup a linq to sql connection. I did it the (what I think is) the standard way. I added a linq to sql class. Then I went to my database explorer and dragged a table in and saved. Whenever I try to load the project in the browser I am getting the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'
```

I am kind of at a loss here. I googled around. I saw some of the standard solutions like add a reference to System.Data.Linq (which I already had but did again) and to make sure debug="true" in my compilation tag and target framework in my compilation tag was the same as the target framework for the project which I did (both are .NET 4.0). I am still getting the error and I have no clue on how to proceed from here.

The error is thrown on the following line of the Conditions.dbml file:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

Comment: Can you post the code that this compilation error is thrown on?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the `System.Data.Linq` assembly. Right click the References folder in your project, go to Add Reference, then make sure you're on the Assemblies tab and add a checkmark next to System.Data.Linq. (These directions are for VS 2013).

Comment: @bob What version of VS are you using, and what tabs do you see?

Comment: I am running Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I see the .NET, COM, Projects, Browse, and Recent tabs.

Comment: @bob In VS 2010, it'd be on the .NET tab.

Comment: @bob After adding the reference, does the `System.Data.Linq.dll` appear in your project's `bin` folder? Does the error happen locally, or just on a server?

Comment: Hmmm, well all I have in the bin folder is Project_name.dll and Project_name.pdb. Regardless, I seem to have solved the issue. It seems that for whatever reason, the dbml file could not be in a child folder. I have now moved it into the project folder and the project is running fine.